# Can you explain Diffrence between two c code snippets below

Tags: c

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
         {
          char name[10];

          strcat(name,"jack");

          printf("%s\n",name );

         }
```

Output:

```
����jack

����jackjack

����jackjackjack

����jackjackjackjack

����jackjackjackjackjack
```

Second  One

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     char name[10]="";

     strcat(name,"jack");

     printf("%s\n",name );

   }
```

Output:

```
jack

jack

jack

jack

jack
```

How the output in first case is so strange ?. whats going in inside?. which concept is this ?

Comment: Because the second is automatically terminated with `\0` which indicates the end of the string, the first doesn't and it results with an *undefined behavior*.

Comment: variable `i` is both undeclared and uninitialized in the code you posted.

Comment: @abelenky It must be initialized before then.

Comment: @Maroun:  the variable may be declared, but that in no way mandates that it is initialized.

Comment: yes, it is initialized to zero before for loop in both cases. stackover flow System is not allowing me to edit it.can any one please edit it.sorry  i didn't mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char name[10];
strcat(name,"jack");
```

Here you just declared an uninitialized string of 10 characters : they are garbage when you try to print it.
Then you append "jack" to it.
On each loop *in your case*, the same address is used so you get back your consecutive "jack" after the random characters.
Indeed, the `printf` keeps trying to print until a `\0` is met: on each loop and because the program re-use the same address, `\0` is overwritten and "jack" is appended again (it is implicitly null-terminated).

```
char name[10]="";
strcat(name,"jack");
```

In that case, the array is initialized to empty on each loop, and each time you append "jack" to it.
Even if the same address is used, the initialization ensure a `\0` before you use `strcat`.

Comment: Can you also explain why for the next iteration it picked the same garbage to which it appended "jack" last time . why not some other garbage ?

Comment: Because the same address is used on the stack (the 1st available one on each iteration) and the memory it points to has not been changed between each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

These two are different because the first one contains the uninitialized array `name`.  Name is just full of whatever random junk was present in that section of the stack.  However, the second snippet contains the array `name` which is initialized with `""`.  Thus it prints nothing, while "jack" is printed the appropriate number of times.

Comment: `char name[10] = 0;` is not valid.

Comment: i tried, compiler said `error: invalid initializer`

Comment: ok i just tried, you are correct.  i will edit my post; i guess i was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the string is not initialized. So first time when you concatenate, you will have some random characters from the stack in "name". The second time you will have the random pattern + jack, and so on.

In the second code snippet, you are initializing the string with the blank string each time when you enter the for